# Correct definition of "bandwidth preserving algorithms" in real-time scheduling?

Tags: terminology, scheduling, real-time, definition

I've seen conflicting definitions for the term "bandwidth preserving algorithms".  The two definitions I've seen are:

1. Any spare CPU capacity is used for aperiodic processes.
2. One or more periodic processes are created to service aperiodic processes (with #1 above being called "slack stealing algorithms").

So, which is correct?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)

Comment: I've gotten rid of the quotes, so it just asks "which is correct".  Is that better?

Comment: Your number 1 and number 2 look exactly the same to me, with the minor distinction that number 2 actually specifies a bandwidth preservation/slack stealing technique.